# Bounty on a "Community wiki" question - what will happen?

Tags: support, bounty, community-wiki

I set a bounty for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102872/unusual-terms-in-mathematics).

However, the question and all answers are marked as "community wiki". (I suppose this marking happened in an automatic way, once the number of answers reached 30)

Will the bounty, once awarded, go to the original poster of chosen answer, or will it just disappear by going to some sort of "community" account?

Answer (score 11):

> #### How does Community Wiki mode affect bounties?
>
> Bounties are not affected by community wiki mode. When you award a bounty to an answer marked community wiki, the reputation bonus will be awarded to the user who posted the original revision of the answer.

[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: It took me a grand total of 45s to find the answer, in the future please be aware that the search feature exists and that questions such as this one are often answered on meta.se.

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding this paragraph to the help center's page about bounties.